# Dash app seems to be frozen due to some processes in the back

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a Dash app that was working just fine moments ago. After a few edits (notably adding some dcc.Store objects), the app got completely frozen: it launches, makes a few callbacks, but then becomes the callbacks don’t work and the editable tables won’t edit (though I can change tabs).

Since I have no error message in the console, it’s like some process is running in the back, but it seems that no callback is running in the back (I put some print calls at the beginning of each callback and can’t see anything in the console).

The last callback edits some data in some dcc.Store ; could it be that there is too much data stored?

Also I am using Dash 1.7.0

Thank you for your help,

Best,

Vincent

Comment: It's possible you have some circular dependencies in your callbacks. What are your callback functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested on the plotly forum, the solution was to look at the JS console of chrome: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. I could see some error messages there.